# jsonPath() not fetching value, restassured

Tags: json, rest-assured

A code is like below

```
    Response response = null;  
    try {  
    response =given().log().everything().when().get().
    then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().response();  
    String a = response.jsonPath().getString("aType");  
    String b = response.jsonPath().getString("bType");  
    System.out.printn(a+b);  
}
```

But I see null output in print instead of value, any clues?

Comment: Are you sure there are fields like "aType" and "bType" in your response
Could you please provide  a sample Response as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved. I should have accessed the full path.